# Dynamic, Table-ish rows of List Items using CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a list of content items, each with a set width but different (variable) heights. Each item in the list will be floated left. The HTML and CSS are as follows:

```
<style type="text/css">
  li{
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
  }
  li img{
  float: right;
  }
</style>

<ul>
  <li><h3>Item One</h3>
      <img src="one.png">
      <p>First item content here</p>
  </li>
  <li><h3>Item Two</h3>
      <img src="two.png">
      <p>Second item content here</p>
  </li>
  <li><h3>Item Three</h3>
      <img src="three.png">
      <p>Third item content here</p>
  </li>
  <li><h3>Item Four</h3>
      <img src="four.png">
      <p>Fourth item content here</p>
  </li>
  <li><h3>Item Five</h3>
      <img src="five.png">
      <p>Fifth item content here</p>
  </li>
</ul>
</style>
```

The problem I have has to do with the way the items float left if there is enough space in a row for 3 items and the second item is taller than then fourth item. The fourth item won't start a new row but will instead place to the right of the second item like this:

[image]

What I want is for the list-items to form a sort of table-like structure that will align each row nicely after the previous row at a height equal to the tallest item of the previous row. Instead of what I have above, I want it to look like this:

[image]

I would also like to be able to scale the width of the containing div such that the items-per-row adjust as necessary. For example, if a containing div is made wider (ie. if the user re-sizes the window) the number of items per row increases to fill the space. Here is an example of the related problem on a wider container:

[image]

And here is what I want it to do:

[image]

Based on a previous question, I don't think there is an easy solution to this so I want to use jQuery to get it done.

What I'm thinking is using jQuery to do something like:

Step 1. Set the width of each element to *elementWidth*

```
var elementWidth = 200; // 200px
```

Step 2. Set a variable *containerWidth* to the width of the overall container

```
var containerWidth = $('#container').width();
```

Step 3. Divide the *containerWidth* by the *elementWidth* to determine the number of elements per row

```
var elementsPerRow = containerWidth / elementWidth;
```

Step 4. Add the property clear:left; each *elementsPerRow*-ith list item

```
for(x = 0, x < (total number of all elements), x + elementsPerRow){
  // set clear:left to this <li>
}
```

I'm not very good (a complete beginner) with JavaScript and jQuery. Can someone please help me put this together into a nice piece of code I can copy and paste (and learn from).

Comment: Are you looking for something like [jQuery Masonry](http://masonry.desandro.com/)?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was looking at jQuery Masonry but I wasn't able to get it to work exactly how I want. Masonry seems to put the items together more tightly than I want. I want each row to be separate and to maintain the space between rows (like in my second diagram where there is space between one and four).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to use `float: left` when you should be using `display: inline-block`. There's no need for using javascript either.

```
li { 
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline-block; }
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/zgNkA/

Comment: just be careful if the audience can use older browsers like IE7, it might not render properly

Comment: Thank you for the great answer. It works! I'm curious, do you have any suggestions for IE7? According to my searches it has "partial support" for inline-block but I haven't tested it yet.

Comment: I haven't personally run into this problem, but it looks like [this article](http://blog.mozilla.com/webdev/2009/02/20/cross-browser-inline-block/) might be able to help you.

Comment: @Wex Would you mind adding: zoom: 1; *display: inline; to the properties? These are absolutely necessary for IE7 to support inline-block from my testing. (The asterisk before "display" is not a typo.)